# How to store values in $localStorage as object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to save all the objects in `$localStorage` as following:

```
$localStorage.userData.currentUser = data.name;
$localStorage.userData.devId= data.id;
$localStorage.userData.userRole = data.roles[0].name;
$localStorage.userData.userId = data.user_id;
```

controller Code:

```
myApp.controller('loginController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'Auth', '$state', '$localStorage',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, Auth, $state, $localStorage) {

        function successAuth(res) {
            $localStorage.token = res;
            $scope.currentUser = $localStorage.token.name;
            console.log("res: ", res);

            Auth.setUserData(res, function(){
                $scope.error = 'No User data available';
            });


            if ($localStorage.token) {
                $state.go("dashboard");
                $scope.isLogin = true;
            } else {
                alert("Invalid username or password");
            }
        }

        $scope.signin = function () {
            var formData = {device_id: myip, platform: "WEB", provider: "EMAIL", uid: $scope.login.username, access_token: "", password: $scope.login.password};
            Auth.signin(formData, successAuth, function () {
                $rootScope.error = 'Invalid credentials';
                console.log($rootScope.error);
            });
        };

        $scope.isLogin = !angular.isUndefined($localStorage.token);
    }]);
```

I tried the following according to [docs](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) but didn't work. Its giving error saying '$storage' of undefined

```
$scope.$storage = $localStorage;

$storage.userData.currentUser = data.name;
$storage.userData.devId= data.id;
$storage.userData.userRole = data.roles[0].name;
$storage.userData.userId = data.user_id;
```

How do I save all data in to `$localStorage` as above ?

Comment: $storage is an Angular service, not a scope variable. can you show the controller code?

Comment: Where do you populate $storage? It's not clear in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like

```
var newData = {
    currentUser : data.name,
    devId : data.id,
    userRole : data.roles[0].name,
    userId : data.user_id
 };

 localStorage.setItem( 'data' , JSON.stringify(newData) );
```

Can Parse 
// For each item in local storage...

```
 for( item in localStorage ) {

        // Parse the JSON string and add to to array
        var newItem = JSON.parse( localStorage[item] );
        $scope.data.push( newItem );

    }
```

Get data by its key

```
localStorage.getItem( 'data' );
```

Comment: I tried some thing similar to this `localStorage.setItem( 'data' , JSON.stringify(newData) );` and it says `$localStorage.setItem()' is not a function

Comment: Its because **$localStorage** is not in angularjs context, Have you tried `localStorage.setItem( 'data' , JSON.stringify(newData)` simply I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code, try this one:

```js
 localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({
   name: "xyz",
   age: 25,
   comp: "abc"
 }));
 user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
 console.log(localStorage)
```

Comment: It says `$localStorage.setItem()' is not a function

Answer (score 0):

In `loginController`, inject `$window` instead of `$localStorage` and use `$window.localStorage.getItem(...)` or even `$window.localStorage["storage_name"]`.
To store/set data in `localStorage`, you could do `$window.localStorage['storage_name'] = angular.toJson( object_to_store)`;